# merge a dict into another, overwriting values including updating lists and sub-dicts (not overwriting the list itself)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary D which contains default settings for my application. It has a complex hierarchy, such as lists, and more dicts inside those lists (e.g. it might have a list of modules, and within each module there are further dicts, sometimes with more lists and more dicts etc).

I also have a small preferences dictionary P which contains an arbitrary subset of this dict (I'm 100% sure that this is a perfect subset).

I'd like to merge this subset P over the default dictionary D.

I thought D.update(P) would work, but this overwrites the lists. 
E.g.

```
D={'i':0, 'j':1, 'modules':[{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}] }
P={'i':10, 'modules':[{'c':30}] }

D.update()

# gives {'i': 10, 'j': 1, 'modules': [{'c': 30}]}
# I'd like {'i': 10, 'j': 1, 'modules': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 30}]}
```

There are a lot of similar posts regarding merging dictionaries in different ways, adding entries etc, but none of them seem to address this exact issue. This seems like a very common task but I couldn't figure out how to do it so I'd appreciate any pointers.
Cheers,

(P.S. I'd also like to maintain the order of all of the lists, as it gets reflected in the GUI)

**EDIT**:
It seems I wasn't very clear in my explanation. Sorry about that. The example above is a very simple toy example. My actual data (when saved to JSON) is about 50K. The hierarchy goes quite deep and I have dicts inside lists inside dicts inside lists etc. Also the atomic update rule wasn't clear apparently (i.e. 0 to 10 is addition or overwriting?). To be clear the atomic update is overwriting. P overwrites D. It's only dicts and lists of dicts which need to further iterated. (I was hoping the user Preferences overwriting Default settings would help visualise this). I also omitted an important detail in the above toy example, and that is that the dictionaries in the list should be matched not by key name (as is in the example above, i.e. the dict with key 'a' is common to P and D), but by value on a specific key. See new toy example below.

```
D={'i':'Hello', 'j':'World', 'modules':[{'name':'a', 'val':1}, {'name':'b', 'val':2}, {'name':'c', 'val':3}, {'name':'d', 'val':4}] }
P={'i':'Goodbye', 'modules':[{'name':'a', 'val':10}, {'name':'c', 'val':30}] }
```

**EDIT2**:
I've added a solution which seems to work. I was hoping for a more concise pythonic solution, but this does the job for now.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: This is likely to need a recursive function; a simple build-in function won't do the job.  Where is your attempt?

Comment: How does the atomic update work?  `i` changes from 0 to 10; is this replacement or addition?

Comment: You also have a deep-semantic disconnection with updating the `c` dictionary within `modules`, since those are individual list elements.  Can those dictionaries have multiple elements?  Can those elements have identical keys?

Comment: Is this exactly what you need to do or there is some general rules? Like how to merge ```'modules':[{'c':30, 'a':20}]``` with ```'modules':[{'c':10}]```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack that merge your current two `dicts`.

I'm aware that is not the "most pythonic" way to do it, but it can handle a `dicts` like yours and give the desired output.

In my answer, i'm using `groupby` and `zip_longest` from itertools `module`.

Here is my answer:

```
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest

D = {'i':0, 'j':1, 'modules':[{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}] }
P = {'i':10, 'modules':[{'c':30}] }

sub = list(D.items()) + list(P.items())

final = {}
for k,v in groupby(sorted(sub, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0]):
    bb = list(v)

    if not isinstance(bb[0][1], list):
        for j in bb:
            final[k] = max(bb, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
    else:
        kk, ff = [], []
        for k_ in zip_longest(*[k[1] for k in bb]):
            kk += [j for j in k_ if j != None] 

        for j,m in groupby(sorted(kk, key= lambda x: list(x.keys())[0]), lambda x: list(x.keys())[0]):
            ff += ff += [dict(max([list(k.items()) for k in list(m)], key=lambda x:x))]

        final[k] = ff

print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'i': 10, 'j': 1, 'modules': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 30}]}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. However as I explain my data is actually a lot deeper in hierarchy and I have dicts inside lists inside dicts inside lists, of arbitrary depth.

Comment: Well, how much is your data's maximum depth? It's a bit tricky to realize what you intend to have bur it's not impossible. If you want, search for max depth of your  dicts and update your question with a representation of the layer of your data. I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for a more pythonic solution (much more concise). Here is a C-like solution (which is more where I come from).

Note: D and P below are very simplified toy examples. In reality they are quite deep with dicts inside lists inside dicts inside lists. This might not cover *all* cases, but it seems to work with my data (~50KBish when saved to json).

Output:

```
In [2]: P
Out[2]: 
{'i': 'Goodbye',
 'modules': [{'name': 'a', 'val': 10}, {'name': 'c', 'val': 30}]}

In [3]: D
Out[3]: 
{'i': 'Hello',
 'j': 'World',
 'modules': [{'name': 'a', 'val': 1},
  {'name': 'b', 'val': 2},
  {'name': 'c', 'val': 3},
  {'name': 'd', 'val': 4}]}

In [4]: merge_dicts_by_name(P, D)
 merge_dicts_by_name  <type 'dict'> <type 'dict'>
 key: .i : Hello overwritten by Goodbye
 key: .modules : 
    merge_dicts_by_name .modules <type 'list'> <type 'list'>
    list item: .modules[0]
       merge_dicts_by_name .modules[0] <type 'dict'> <type 'dict'>
       key: .modules[0].name : a overwritten by a
       key: .modules[0].val : 1 overwritten by 10
    list item: .modules[1]
       merge_dicts_by_name .modules[1] <type 'dict'> <type 'dict'>
       key: .modules[1].name : c overwritten by c
       key: .modules[1].val : 3 overwritten by 30

In [5]: D
Out[5]: 
{'i': 'Goodbye',
 'j': 'World',
 'modules': [{'name': 'a', 'val': 10},
  {'name': 'b', 'val': 2},
  {'name': 'c', 'val': 30},
  {'name': 'd', 'val': 4}]}
```

Code:

```
def merge_dicts_by_name(P, D, id_key='name', root='', depth=0, verbose=True, indent='   '):
    '''
    merge from dict (or list of dicts) P into D. 
    i.e. can think of D as Default settings, and P as a subset containing user Preferences.
    Any value in P or D can be a dict or a list of dicts
    in which case same behaviour will apply (through recursion):
        lists are iterated and dicts are matched between P and D
        dicts are matched via an id_key (only at same hierarchy depth / level)
        matching dicts are updated with same behaviour
        for anything else P overwrites D

    P : dict or list of dicts (e.g. containing user Preferences, subset of D)
    D : dict or list of dicts (e.g. Default settings)
    id_key : the key by which sub-dicts are compared against (e.g. 'name')
    root : for keeping track of full path during recursion
    depth : keep track of recursion depth (for indenting)
    verbose : dump progress to console
    indent : with what to indent (if verbose)
    '''

    if verbose:
        indent_full = indent * depth
        print(indent_full, 'merge_dicts_by_name', root, type(P), type(D))

    if type(P)==list: # D and P are lists of dicts
        assert(type(D)==type(P))
        for p_i, p_dict in enumerate(P): # iterate dicts in P
            path = root + '[' + str(p_i) + ']'
            if verbose: print(indent_full, 'list item:', path)
            d_id = p_dict[id_key] # get name of current dict
            # find corresponding dict in D 
            d_dict = D[ next(i for (i,d) in enumerate(D) if d[id_key] == d_id) ]
            merge_dicts_by_name(p_dict, d_dict, id_key=id_key, root=path, depth=depth+1, verbose=verbose, indent=indent)

    elif type(P)==dict:
        assert(type(D)==type(P))
        for k in P:
            path = root + '.' + k
            if verbose: print(indent_full, 'key:', path, end=' : ')
            if k in D:
                if type(P[k]) in [dict, list]:
                    print()
                    merge_dicts_by_name(P[k], D[k], id_key=id_key, root=path, depth=depth+1, verbose=verbose, indent=indent)
                else:
                    if verbose: print(D[k], 'overwritten by', P[k])
                    D[k] = P[k]

            else:
                print(indent_full, 'Warning: Key {} in P not found in D'.format(path))

    else:
        print(indent_full, "Warning: Don't know what to do with these types", type(P), type(D))
```